# modify the appearance of the page

Tags: sharepoint

I've never worked before with SharePoint, that's why maybe my question is so basic but I could't find out the way to do this.

This picture contains what I've done so far. 
I'm working with a SharePoint where I don't have all the administrator permitions, that's why I don't if teh option I need is disabled or just I can't find it.

[image: index page]

You can see I have my page divided into 3 parts:

-the Left section, where I have a scheme of what i have in the middle.
-the Middle seccion, where I have the buttons. 
-**The Right section, this section I don't really need it so I want to delete it** but I couldn't find the way to do it, and although I dont have anything there, It have a blank.

[image: picture of what i want]

This is all the options I have in configuration:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can add the code below into script editor web part to remove the right web part zone.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div[zoneTitle='Right']").closest("tr").children("td").eq(0).attr("width","100%");
    $("div[zoneTitle='Right']").closest("td").hide();
})
</script>
```

Or we can use CSS style to hide the Right section.

```
<style>
div[zoneTitle='Right']{
    display:none;
}
</style>
```